# Should non-aggregate entities be public in Unit of work in DDD?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, domain-driven-design, unit-of-work

I was studying DDD, aggregate pattern, EF, repository pattern and unit of work pattern I'm a little bit confused. So I came here to ask a question.

Here's an example: Student (main entity), Address, Contact. Those three entities creates an aggregate. One of DDD/Aggregate pattern rules is that I can interact with Address only through Student. I can't add/remove/update an address alone. It has to be done through Student. Second rule is that changes in Student, Address and Contact must be done in single transaction. And here is my confusion:

I have repository for EVERY table in database. It's because every entity must have CRUD operations. But every repository is internal. The only class that I expose public (from my Data dll) is Context and UnitOfWork. In UoW I have declared all repositories:

Question:
**Is it a rule, that in UoW I should have only repositories of main entities of aggregates?**

In another words:
Do I need Address repository in Unit Of Work?

Comment: Repositories should be publicly exposed to clients and there should only be repositories for root aggregates. The repositories should collaborate with the unit of work.

Comment: @plalx so, how I can insert person's address into address table without AddressRepository ?

Comment: If Address is part of the Student aggregate then it's the responsability of the StudentRepository to do that.

Answer (score 0):

DDD can be interpreted in various ways however we only ever have repositories for aggregate roots, where each repo will usually expose GetAll, GetById and Save methods.

When you refer to both Context and UoW, I dont understand what you mean by this. We achieve the Unit of Work pattern via the repo Save function for each aggregate. We dont have a Context object either